# JQuery mouseover issue

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I am using the following script and there is placeholder div. when i mouseover the div play button should come over the placeholder.

I have three placeholder in a row. When I mouseover the one particular placeholder, all the play button appears. What I need is when i mouseover the placeholder only that play image should appear.

Hope you can understand my question. Could anyone please help me to do this?

```
jQuery.noConflict();
       jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('.placeholder').mouseover(function(){
               jQuery('.play').show('show');
        });
        jQuery('.placeholder').mouseleave(function(){
               jQuery('.play').hide('hide');
        });
      });
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="placeholder item"><div class="play"><img src="images/play_ico.jpg"></div></div>
 <div class="placeholder item"><div class="play"><img src="images/play_ico.jpg"></div></div>
 <div class="placeholder item"><div class="play"><img src="images/play_ico.jpg"></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.placeholder{
    width:120px;
    float:left;
    background:#ccc;
    height:67px;
    position:relative;
}

.play{
    width:120px;
    height:67px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:none;
    background:#000;
    opacity:0.4;
filter:alpha(opacity=40);
}
```

Comment: you had multiple `play` classes? could u show up ur markup lang

Comment: You shouldn't be passing show "show" and hide "hide", they take no parameters as you're using them: http://api.jquery.com/show/ http://api.jquery.com/hide

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
    jQuery('.placeholder').mouseenter(function(){
           jQuery(this).find('.play').show();
    });
    jQuery('.placeholder').mouseleave(function(){
           jQuery(this).find('.play').hide();
    });
```

as an alternative you can use `hover` method:

```
    jQuery('.placeholder').hover(function() {
           jQuery(this).find('.play').show();
    }, function() {
           jQuery(this).find('.play').hide();
    })
```

Comment: +1 *minor suggestion bruv* I reckon you should mention about `mouseenter` as well man! might be that what is needed with `mouse leave` :)

Comment: This works, and I upvoted, but I would use jQuery('.placeholder').hover( function(){}, function(){} ); here. :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're doin this right, and do you really need to use noConflict ?

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.placeholder').on({
        mouseenter: function(){
           jQuery('.play', this).show('slow');
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
           jQuery('.play', this).hide('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

or just

```
jQuery('.placeholder').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
    jQuery('.play', this).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

off the top of my head, I don't think that 'show' and 'hide' are valid params to pass to the show and hide functions, unless you're using custom animations by those names?

try just

```
jQuery('.play').show();
```

and

```
jQuery('.play').hide();
```

unless you want them to animate in and out, then use

```
jQuery('.play').show('slow');
```

and

```
jQuery('.play').hide('slow');
```

or the equivalent :)

http://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: How does it differ from OPs Qn?

Comment: he's passing 'show' and 'hide' into the show and hide methods.